# ¿Como validar que una pregunta tenga ambos signos de interrogacion?

Tags: java, regex

Necesito validar con expresiones regulares que se hace una pregunta esta deba tener ambos signos de interrogación

incorrecto: como estas?
incorrecto: ¿como estas
correcto: ¿como estas?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes Guillermo, por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Entiendo que quieres que un usuario introduzca una pregunta en algún tipo de formulario. Si es así implementaría JavaScript. Cojeria el String y le diría si el primer carácter del string es "¿" y el ultimo es "?", que continué con el envió del campo. Tambien podrias decir que si en alguno de los casos en los que falta el caracter lo introduces automaticamente.

Answer (score 2):

la expresion regular para validar ambos signos de interrogacion es la siguiente:

^\¿.*?\?$

que quiere decir:

- comienzo de linea (^)
- signo de apertura de interrogacion (\¿): la interrogacion es un caracter especial, necesita que le pongas la barra
- cualquier conjunto de caracteres (.*?): esta interrogacion es un caracter especial para forzar el menor tamaño posible del conjunto de caracteres, no el cierre de interrogacion.
- signo de cierre de interrogacion (\?): la interrogacion es un caracter especial, necesita que le pongas la barra
- fin de linea ($)

Es una expresion muy basica que tiene muchos defectos pero segun para lo que la necesites puede servirte. En caso de necesitar afinar mas, describe el contexto en el que quieres meterla.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola Eorahil, gracias por responder pero las  preguntas de baja calidad, por no explicar lo intentado, no es conventiente responderlas. Has de esperar a que el autor mejore su pregunta para no hacerle la tarea. Un saludo!